# Iphone - UIImageView not showing up

Tags: iphone

I have created a UIImageView in Interface Builder. When I run the application on the simulator the image shows up, when I run the application on the device the image doesn't show up. Any help is welcome. Thank you!!!

Comment: Project target framework ? IOS version ?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the application off the device and re-deploying? (Some resources seem to have issues.) Also, what format of image are you using? (encoding/dimensions/DPI, etc.)

Comment: Make sure you use the correct case in the file name throughout your project. The phone's file system is case-sensitive, the simulator's is not.

Comment: @Björn - Doubt he could have selected it incorrectly within IB (unless he typed the name instead of using the dropdown). Then again, perhaps it's being populated programmatically.

Comment: IOS is 4.2, it is a standard issue build. I just noticed this happening...There is nothing special about the app. It is built using the latest Xcode version.

Answer (score 2):

Check your image format, sometimes the image format may not be supported by the device.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out the problem...Thank for the help. The issue was I copied the image from the internet and saved it with a .png file extension without converting it. Then I brought the image into xcode. After I used gimp to convert my image to a .png and replaced it inside xcode it worked properly.